# How to identify form elements in an IFRAME

Tags: jquery, iframe, input, textarea, prettyphoto

I am trying to determine if the `value` in a `<input type="text">` and the value in a `<textarea>` changes so I can launch an AJAX call to the server. The script simply loops through and shows me every `id` and not just the ones in the current `IFRAME`.

I know how to do the AJAX call and the backend scripting, I just can't figure out how to capture if the `value` of the form elements change in any given [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) `IFRAME`. My prettyPhoto frames are created dynamically and there are over 800 elements in the `FORM`.

I have the following jQuery:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; // Needed for AJAX to work in certain older browsers and versions

$(document).ready(function(){

    // load each PP Frame
    $('a[rel^="prettyPhoto"]').prettyPhoto({
        social_tools: false,
        changepicturecallback: function() {
            var abc = $('input.inputText').val();
            alert(abc);
        }
    });

}); // end .ready()
```

Any thoughts or help is tremendously appreciated.

```
<form id="my-form" name="my-form"><div class="rowhighlight" style="clear:both">

<div style="clear:both">
    <p style="float:left;width:40px;text-align:right;background-color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;margin-left:60px;padding-right:10px;"><a href="#n0076-1" rel="prettyPhoto[n0076]" title="App Title<br />2012">76</a></p>
    <div style="display:none;">
        <a href="#n0076-2" rel="prettyPhoto[n0076]" title="App Title<br />2012"></a>
        <a href="#n0076-3" rel="prettyPhoto[n0076]" title="App Title<br />2012"></a>
        <a href="#n0076-4" rel="prettyPhoto[n0076]" title="App Title<br />2012"></a>
    </div>
    <p style="float:left;width:240px;background-color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color:inherit;">Person 76</p>
    <p style="float:left;width:240px;background-color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color:inherit;">Person 76-A<span style="font-size:0.8125em;padding-left:8px;">(Type)</span></p>
    <p style="float:left;width:180px;background-color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color:inherit;">3/1/12 at 10:22am (Thu)</p>
    <p style="float:left;width:60px;text-align:right;background-color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color:inherit;">0</p>
    <p style="float:left;width:60px;text-align:right;background-color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color:inherit;padding-right:10px;">0.00</p>
</div>

<div id="n0076-1" style="display:none;width:600px;">
<h1 style="float:left;margin:6px 0 8px 6px;padding:0;border:none;">Header 1</h1>
<h2 style="float:right;margin:9px 8px; 8px 0;padding:0;border:none;">Header 2</h2>
<div style="clear:both;margin:0 6px;padding:4px 10px;background-color:#dedede">

    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888">Name 1:</span> <span style="font-weight:bold">Person 76</span></p>
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:11px">Name 2:</span>Person 76-A (Type)&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;Description</p>
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:9px">Date:</span> March 1, 2012 at 10:22am</p>
</div>

<div style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding-left:4px;margin:0;padding-right:10px;font-size:0.875em;line-height:1.375em;margin-top:10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a magna et massa ultrices porta ut a sem. Nulla eu mauris eget nunc sagittis ornare. Mauris convallis posuere nisi, non posuere turpis mattis ut. Quisque venenatis, dolor ac placerat posuere, velit purus adipiscing libero, eu suscipit nibh justo non nunc. Praesent non odio in nunc tempus volutpat sed ac metus. Nam eleifend adipiscing ipsum, ultricies adipiscing purus accumsan eu. Nulla tincidunt tincidunt varius. Sed non aliquet nunc. Mauris in pulvinar eros. Ut elementum pulvinar interdum. Fusce pulvinar posuere sollicitudin. Nam ultricies auctor sapien, quis eleifend ipsum pharetra hendrerit.</div><!--start form 1-->
<div style="margin-top:36px;display:block"><input class="textInput" id="es_user_2012_0076_1" type="text" value="0" style="float:left;margin:0 2px 0 2px;padding:0;width:60px;height:60px;border:1px solid #999;color:#777;text-align:center;font-size:3.5em;" /><textarea class="noteInput" onFocus="$(this).val('')" id="en_user_2012_0076_1" style="float:left;margin:0 2px 0 2px;padding:2px;width:424px;height:56px;border:1px solid #999;color:#369;text-align:left;font-size:0.75em;">In box to left, enter 1-5 (1=low &amp; 5=high). Use this box for optional notes.</textarea></div>
<!--end form 1-->
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div> <!-- end 0076-1 -->
<div id="n0076-2" style="display:none;width:600px;">
<h1 style="float:left;margin:6px 0 8px 6px;padding:0;border:none;">Header 1</h1>
<h2 style="float:right;margin:9px 8px; 8px 0;padding:0;border:none;">Header 2</h2>
<div style="clear:both;margin:0 6px;padding:4px 10px;background-color:#dedede">
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888">Name 1:</span> <span style="font-weight:bold">Person 76</span></p>

    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:11px">Name 2:</span>Person 76-A (Type)&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;Description</p>
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:9px">Date:</span> March 1, 2012 at 10:22am</p>
</div>
<div style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding-left:4px;margin:0;padding-right:10px;font-size:0.875em;line-height:1.375em;margin-top:10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a magna et massa ultrices porta ut a sem. Nulla eu mauris eget nunc sagittis ornare. Mauris convallis posuere nisi, non posuere turpis mattis ut. Quisque venenatis, dolor ac placerat posuere, velit purus adipiscing libero, eu suscipit nibh justo non nunc. Praesent non odio in nunc tempus volutpat sed ac metus. Nam eleifend adipiscing ipsum, ultricies adipiscing purus accumsan eu. Nulla tincidunt tincidunt varius. Sed non aliquet nunc. Mauris in pulvinar eros. Ut elementum pulvinar interdum. Fusce pulvinar posuere sollicitudin. Nam ultricies auctor sapien, quis eleifend ipsum pharetra hendrerit.</div><!--start form 2-->
<div style="margin-top:36px;display:block"><input class="textInput" id="es_user_2012_0076_2" type="text" value="0" style="float:left;margin:0 2px 0 2px;padding:0;width:60px;height:60px;border:1px solid #999;color:#777;text-align:center;font-size:3.5em;" /><textarea class="noteInput" onFocus="$(this).val('')" id="en_user_2012_0076_2" style="float:left;margin:0 2px 0 2px;padding:2px;width:424px;height:56px;border:1px solid #999;color:#369;text-align:left;font-size:0.75em;">In box to left, enter 1-5 (1=low &amp; 5=high). Use this box for optional notes.</textarea></div>
<!--end form 2-->

<div style="clear:both;"></div></div> <!-- end 0076-2 -->
<div id="n0076-3" style="display:none;width:600px;">
<h1 style="float:left;margin:6px 0 8px 6px;padding:0;border:none;">Header 1</h1>
<h2 style="float:right;margin:9px 8px; 8px 0;padding:0;border:none;">Header 2</h2>
<div style="clear:both;margin:0 6px;padding:4px 10px;background-color:#dedede">
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888">Name 1:</span> <span style="font-weight:bold">Person 76</span></p>
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:11px">Name 2:</span>Person 76-A (Type)&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;Description</p>

    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:9px">Date:</span> March 1, 2012 at 10:22am</p>
</div>
<div style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding-left:4px;margin:0;padding-right:10px;font-size:0.875em;line-height:1.375em;margin-top:10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a magna et massa ultrices porta ut a sem. Nulla eu mauris eget nunc sagittis ornare. Mauris convallis posuere nisi, non posuere turpis mattis ut. Quisque venenatis, dolor ac placerat posuere, velit purus adipiscing libero, eu suscipit nibh justo non nunc. Praesent non odio in nunc tempus volutpat sed ac metus. Nam eleifend adipiscing ipsum, ultricies adipiscing purus accumsan eu. Nulla tincidunt tincidunt varius. Sed non aliquet nunc. Mauris in pulvinar eros. Ut elementum pulvinar interdum. Fusce pulvinar posuere sollicitudin. Nam ultricies auctor sapien, quis eleifend ipsum pharetra hendrerit.</div><!--start form 3-->
<div style="margin-top:36px;display:block"><input class="textInput" id="es_user_2012_0076_3" type="text" value="0" style="float:left;margin:0 2px 0 2px;padding:0;width:60px;height:60px;border:1px solid #999;color:#777;text-align:center;font-size:3.5em;" /><textarea class="noteInput" onFocus="$(this).val('')" id="en_user_2012_0076_3" style="float:left;margin:0 2px 0 2px;padding:2px;width:424px;height:56px;border:1px solid #999;color:#369;text-align:left;font-size:0.75em;">In box to left, enter 1-5 (1=low &amp; 5=high). Use this box for optional notes.</textarea></div>
<!--end form 3-->
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div> <!-- end 0076-3 -->
<div id="n0076-4" style="display:none;width:600px;">
<h1 style="float:left;margin:6px 0 8px 6px;padding:0;border:none;">Header 1</h1>
<h2 style="float:right;margin:9px 8px; 8px 0;padding:0;border:none;">Header 2</h2>

<div style="clear:both;margin:0 6px;padding:4px 10px;background-color:#dedede">
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888">Name 1:</span> <span style="font-weight:bold">Person 76</span></p>
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:11px">Name 2:</span>Person 76-A (Type)&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;Description</p>
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:9px">Date:</span> March 1, 2012 at 10:22am</p>

</div>
<div style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding-left:4px;margin:0;padding-right:10px;font-size:0.875em;line-height:1.375em;margin-top:10px"><span class="ltOrange">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a magna et massa ultrices porta ut a sem. Nulla eu mauris eget nunc sagittis ornare. Mauris convallis posuere nisi, non posuere turpis mattis ut. Quisque venenatis, dolor ac placerat posuere, velit purus adipiscing libero, eu suscipit nibh justo non nunc. Praesent non odio in nunc tempus volutpat sed ac metus. Nam eleifend adipiscing ipsum, ultricies adipiscing purus accumsan eu. Nulla tincidunt tincidunt varius. Sed non aliquet nunc. Mauris in pulvinar eros. Ut elementum pulvinar interdum. Fusce pulvinar posuere sollicitudin. Nam ultricies auctor sapien, quis eleifend ipsum pharetra hendrerit.</span></div><div style="clear:both;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding-top:20px;"></div></div> <!-- end 0076-4 -->
<div class="rowhighlight" style="clear:both">

    <p style="float:left;width:40px;text-align:right;background-color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;margin-left:60px;padding-right:10px;"><a href="#n0108-1" rel="prettyPhoto[n0108]" title="App Title<br />2012">108</a></p>
    <div style="display:none;">
        <a href="#n0108-2" rel="prettyPhoto[n0108]" title="App Title<br />2012"></a>
        <a href="#n0108-3" rel="prettyPhoto[n0108]" title="App Title<br />2012"></a>
        <a href="#n0108-4" rel="prettyPhoto[n0108]" title="App Title<br />2012"></a>
    </div>
    <p style="float:left;width:240px;background-color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color:inherit;">Person 108</p>
    <p style="float:left;width:240px;background-color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color:inherit;">Person 108-A<span style="font-size:0.8125em;padding-left:8px;">(Type)</span></p>
    <p style="float:left;width:180px;background-color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color:inherit;">3/2/12 at 11:12pm (Fri)</p>
    <p style="float:left;width:60px;text-align:right;background-color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color:inherit;">0</p>
    <p style="float:left;width:60px;text-align:right;background-color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color:inherit;padding-right:10px;">0.00</p>
</div>

<div id="n0108-1" style="display:none;width:600px;">
<h1 style="float:left;margin:6px 0 8px 6px;padding:0;border:none;">Header 1</h1>
<h2 style="float:right;margin:9px 8px; 8px 0;padding:0;border:none;">Header 2</h2>
<div style="clear:both;margin:0 6px;padding:4px 10px;background-color:#dedede">
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888">Name 1:</span> <span style="font-weight:bold">Person 108</span></p>

    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:11px">Name 2:</span>Person 108-A (Type)&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;Description</p>
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:9px">Date:</span> March 2, 2012 at 11:12pm</p>
</div>
<div style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding-left:4px;margin:0;padding-right:10px;font-size:0.875em;line-height:1.375em;margin-top:10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a magna et massa ultrices porta ut a sem. Nulla eu mauris eget nunc sagittis ornare. Mauris convallis posuere nisi, non posuere turpis mattis ut. Quisque venenatis, dolor ac placerat posuere, velit purus adipiscing libero, eu suscipit nibh justo non nunc. Praesent non odio in nunc tempus volutpat sed ac metus. Nam eleifend adipiscing ipsum, ultricies adipiscing purus accumsan eu. Nulla tincidunt tincidunt varius. Sed non aliquet nunc. Mauris in pulvinar eros. Ut elementum pulvinar interdum. Fusce pulvinar posuere sollicitudin. Nam ultricies auctor sapien, quis eleifend ipsum pharetra hendrerit.</div><!--start form 1-->
<div style="margin-top:36px;display:block"><input class="textInput" id="es_user_2012_0108_1" type="text" value="0" style="float:left;margin:0 2px 0 2px;padding:0;width:60px;height:60px;border:1px solid #999;color:#777;text-align:center;font-size:3.5em;" /><textarea class="noteInput" onFocus="$(this).val('')" id="en_user_2012_0108_1" style="float:left;margin:0 2px 0 2px;padding:2px;width:424px;height:56px;border:1px solid #999;color:#369;text-align:left;font-size:0.75em;">In box to left, enter 1-5 (1=low &amp; 5=high). Use this box for optional notes.</textarea></div>
<!--end form 1-->

<div style="clear:both;"></div></div> <!-- end 0108-1 -->
<div id="n0108-2" style="display:none;width:600px;">
<h1 style="float:left;margin:6px 0 8px 6px;padding:0;border:none;">Header 1</h1>
<h2 style="float:right;margin:9px 8px; 8px 0;padding:0;border:none;">Header 2</h2>
<div style="clear:both;margin:0 6px;padding:4px 10px;background-color:#dedede">
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888">Name 1:</span> <span style="font-weight:bold">Person 108</span></p>
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:11px">Name 2:</span>Person 108-A (Type)&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;Description</p>

    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:9px">Date:</span> March 2, 2012 at 11:12pm</p>
</div>
<div style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding-left:4px;margin:0;padding-right:10px;font-size:0.875em;line-height:1.375em;margin-top:10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a magna et massa ultrices porta ut a sem. Nulla eu mauris eget nunc sagittis ornare. Mauris convallis posuere nisi, non posuere turpis mattis ut. Quisque venenatis, dolor ac placerat posuere, velit purus adipiscing libero, eu suscipit nibh justo non nunc. Praesent non odio in nunc tempus volutpat sed ac metus. Nam eleifend adipiscing ipsum, ultricies adipiscing purus accumsan eu. Nulla tincidunt tincidunt varius. Sed non aliquet nunc. Mauris in pulvinar eros. Ut elementum pulvinar interdum. Fusce pulvinar posuere sollicitudin. Nam ultricies auctor sapien, quis eleifend ipsum pharetra hendrerit.</div><!--start form 2-->
<div style="margin-top:36px;display:block"><input class="textInput" id="es_user_2012_0108_2" type="text" value="0" style="float:left;margin:0 2px 0 2px;padding:0;width:60px;height:60px;border:1px solid #999;color:#777;text-align:center;font-size:3.5em;" /><textarea class="noteInput" onFocus="$(this).val('')" id="en_user_2012_0108_2" style="float:left;margin:0 2px 0 2px;padding:2px;width:424px;height:56px;border:1px solid #999;color:#369;text-align:left;font-size:0.75em;">In box to left, enter 1-5 (1=low &amp; 5=high). Use this box for optional notes.</textarea></div>
<!--end form 2-->
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div> <!-- end 0108-2 -->
<div id="n0108-3" style="display:none;width:600px;">
<h1 style="float:left;margin:6px 0 8px 6px;padding:0;border:none;">Header 1</h1>
<h2 style="float:right;margin:9px 8px; 8px 0;padding:0;border:none;">Header 2</h2>

<div style="clear:both;margin:0 6px;padding:4px 10px;background-color:#dedede">
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888">Name 1:</span> <span style="font-weight:bold">Person 108</span></p>
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:11px">Name 2:</span>Person 108-A (Type)&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;Description</p>
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:9px">Date:</span> March 2, 2012 at 11:12pm</p>

</div>
<div style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding-left:4px;margin:0;padding-right:10px;font-size:0.875em;line-height:1.375em;margin-top:10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a magna et massa ultrices porta ut a sem. Nulla eu mauris eget nunc sagittis ornare. Mauris convallis posuere nisi, non posuere turpis mattis ut. Quisque venenatis, dolor ac placerat posuere, velit purus adipiscing libero, eu suscipit nibh justo non nunc. Praesent non odio in nunc tempus volutpat sed ac metus. Nam eleifend adipiscing ipsum, ultricies adipiscing purus accumsan eu. Nulla tincidunt tincidunt varius. Sed non aliquet nunc. Mauris in pulvinar eros. Ut elementum pulvinar interdum. Fusce pulvinar posuere sollicitudin. Nam ultricies auctor sapien, quis eleifend ipsum pharetra hendrerit.</div><!--start form 3-->
<div style="margin-top:36px;display:block"><input class="textInput" id="es_user_2012_0108_3" type="text" value="0" style="float:left;margin:0 2px 0 2px;padding:0;width:60px;height:60px;border:1px solid #999;color:#777;text-align:center;font-size:3.5em;" /><textarea class="noteInput" onFocus="$(this).val('')" id="en_user_2012_0108_3" style="float:left;margin:0 2px 0 2px;padding:2px;width:424px;height:56px;border:1px solid #999;color:#369;text-align:left;font-size:0.75em;">In box to left, enter 1-5 (1=low &amp; 5=high). Use this box for optional notes.</textarea></div>
<!--end form 3-->
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div> <!-- end 0108-3 -->
<div id="n0108-4" style="display:none;width:600px;">
<h1 style="float:left;margin:6px 0 8px 6px;padding:0;border:none;">Header 1</h1>
<h2 style="float:right;margin:9px 8px; 8px 0;padding:0;border:none;">Header 2</h2>
<div style="clear:both;margin:0 6px;padding:4px 10px;background-color:#dedede">
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888">Name 1:</span> <span style="font-weight:bold">Person 108</span></p>

    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:11px">Name 2:</span>Person 108-A (Type)&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;Description</p>
    <p style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0.6875em;line-height:1.25em;"><span style="color:#888;padding-right:9px">Date:</span> March 2, 2012 at 11:12pm</p>
</div>
<div style="color:#333;text-align:left;padding-left:4px;margin:0;padding-right:10px;font-size:0.875em;line-height:1.375em;margin-top:10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a magna et massa ultrices porta ut a sem. Nulla eu mauris eget nunc sagittis ornare. Mauris convallis posuere nisi, non posuere turpis mattis ut. Quisque venenatis, dolor ac placerat posuere, velit purus adipiscing libero, eu suscipit nibh justo non nunc. Praesent non odio in nunc tempus volutpat sed ac metus. Nam eleifend adipiscing ipsum, ultricies adipiscing purus accumsan eu. Nulla tincidunt tincidunt varius. Sed non aliquet nunc. Mauris in pulvinar eros. Ut elementum pulvinar interdum. Fusce pulvinar posuere sollicitudin. Nam ultricies auctor sapien, quis eleifend ipsum pharetra hendrerit.</div><!--start form 4-->
<div style="margin-top:36px;display:block"><input class="textInput" id="es_user_2012_0108_4" type="text" value="0" style="float:left;margin:0 2px 0 2px;padding:0;width:60px;height:60px;border:1px solid #999;color:#777;text-align:center;font-size:3.5em;" /><textarea class="noteInput" onFocus="$(this).val('')" id="en_user_2012_0108_4" style="float:left;margin:0 2px 0 2px;padding:2px;width:424px;height:56px;border:1px solid #999;color:#369;text-align:left;font-size:0.75em;">In box to left, enter 1-5 (1=low &amp; 5=high). Use this box for optional notes.</textarea></div>
<!--end form 4-->

<div style="clear:both;"></div></div> <!-- end 0108-4 -->

</div></form>
```

P.S. I know how to use style sheets and will move all styles into a sheet once I finish developing. I have a knack (bad habit maybe) of inline styling during development because things change too often and I prefer to work on 1 doc at a time.

Next attempt using [at]JF's answer

```
<script>

jQuery.support.cors = true; // needed for ajax to work in certain older browsers and versions

$(document).ready(function(){

/*
    // load scores and notes in each PP Frame
    $('a[rel^="prettyPhoto"]').prettyPhoto({
        social_tools: false,
        changepicturecallback: function() {
            var abc = $('input.inputText').val();
            //alert(abc);
        }
    });
*/

    var $pps = $("a[rel^=prettyPhoto]"),
        $inputs = $('input.textInput'),
        $textinputscls = $('.textInput'),
        $textinputs = $('input.textInput');

    var ppcallback = function(){
        $textinputs = $('input.textInput');

        //console.log($textinputs); // don't need
        //console.log($textinputs.val()); // don't need
        console.log('id: ' + $textinputs.attr('id')); // very close...returns 1st ID only
    };

    $pps.prettyPhoto({
        social_tools: false,
        changepicturecallback: ppcallback
    });

    //console.log($pps); // don't need

    // post scores and notes each time they change -- THIS WORKS
    $(this).change(function(e) {
        var elemId = e.target.id;
        var elemValue = e.target.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://mydomain.com/dir/ajax/updateMySQL.php?actionString=" + elemId + '_' + elemValue
        });
    });

}); // end .ready()

//  window.parent.closePP();

</script>
```

Comment: jQuery provides [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`$.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for monitoring events of element's that are dynamically added/removed from the DOM. Note, ignore [`$.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), as it's deprecated and will be removed eventually (not to mention it's not very performant). If you find yourself needing to monitor for non-traditional events (like when an element is added/removed), you might try [Live Query](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs), which is a jQuery plugin and fairly new(er); performance may vary.

Comment: Ok, thanks @JaredFarrish. The dilemma I have is I need to use something other than event catcher. PP's `changepicturecallback:` works fine to bring me into control on any given PP iFrame. I need to use the value in a form field that is in the current iFrame when it is in focus. Example, I have about 100 dynamically built <input type="text"> elements that appear only once in any given frame. Their id is coded "2012_0001_1", "2012_0002_1", "2012_0003_1", "2012_0004_1", ..., "2012_0100_1". So how do I use jQuery to handle the value in "2012_0051_1" when I eventually give focus to the 51st frame?

Comment: You need to put a class on those inputs so you can get to them as a group (or, class), ie, `<input class="myDynamicInput" id="2012_0001_1"/>`, and then `$('input.myDynamicInput')`. And just in case you need to know how to get *into* the `iframe`, you can use [`$.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/#example-1).

Comment: Also, something is amiss with the code you posted; it's not correct, there's too many `});` and it looks like the lone `}` is out of place.

Comment: @JaredFarrish. I revised my code in the question to try what you are suggesting. Nothing happens when I view any PP frame.

Comment: Do you get an error in Firebug or Chrome Console? Have you verified you're not breaking the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)?

Comment: @JaredFarrish. No errors in the console. The alert just pops-up with "undefined".

Comment: If the above code is running in the parent `document`, and the `input.inputText` element you're looking for is within an `iframe` element *in that parent `document`*, you'll need to access the `iframe`'s `document` from the parent, *then* run your selector on that context. That `iframe` is a separate document, in other words, from that parent (containing) document. This is why I say you need to review what `$.contents()` does in relation to `iframe` document access. See this fiddle for a demonstration of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/4tJDN/

Comment: @JaredFarrish -- well, if it helps, I have pasted an excerpt from my dynamic html document. There are about 110 instances of excerpt. Each time PrettyPhoto's frames come up they come as inline text and there are 4 frames per instance. My challenge is that I want to perform an ajax call to the server at each focus of each frame. I can handle the ajax. What I can't figure out is how to use jQuery to capture `.inputText` `#en_user_2012_0108_1`, `#en_user_2012_0108_2`, `#en_user_2012_0108_3`, and `#en_user_2012_0108_4` as each frame comes into focus.

Comment: Do you have a link I can review? You can delete the comment, I'll let you know when I see it, if you're worried about that.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I wish I could. The app is behind a private firewall and I the only logon ID I have is the one that gets me to all of our organizational restricted apps (at a major University). I just struggle with how to get at the <input> element at loading of each frame. I do appreciate your wanting to help out and stick with this though....thanks.

Comment: You need to make a working example that demonstrates as-accurate-as-possible-markup/code that I can look at. I need to see the big(ger) picture. jsFiddle seems to be down right now, but JS Bin is up: http://jsbin.com/#javascript,html,live Can you put together a working demo that's close to what you actual overall markup/iframes is?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'll have to rebuild a prototype and publish in the public domain. I think I looked and saw you are in the UK. Correct? If so, It's what 4am there? I can post something tomorrow if you think you will want to look at it. I am in New York.

Comment: I'm in Denton, Tx. It's about 10pm here. Another option is, if you could email me the actual client-side document source code and markup for the parent and `iframe` content, I could potentially find what I'm looking for. You can Google me and find my email address readily enough.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I put something together and get it to you shortly

Comment: @JaredFarrish can you look at http://sportame.com/test/index.html and tell me how to capture the `es_` or `en_` value upon frame load? Thanks

Comment: I'll take a look at it. It may be tomorrow evening, if I go to bed like I know I should, but let me take a quick look and see if I can put together something quickly.

Comment: @JaredFarrish. No rush, no hurry. I do appreciate any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, using the following code, I was able to what I believe you are wanting to be able to do, which is access elements which are within the prettyPhoto displays. I'll have to provide a more detailed answer later, so feel free to leave some comments if you have any questions.

Note as well that you need to have the console open to see the code "work"; it output to `console.log()`.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $pps = $("a[rel^=prettyPhoto]"),
        $inputs = $('input.textInput'),
        $textinputscls = $('.textInput'),
        $textinputs = $('input.textInput');

    var ppcallback = function(){
        $textinputs = $('input.textInput');

        console.log($textinputs);
        console.log($textinputs.val());
    };

    $pps.prettyPhoto({
        social_tools: false,
        changepicturecallback: ppcallback
    });

    console.log($pps);
});
</script>
```

http://jfcoder.com/test/prettyphotoiframe.html

Comment: Thanks @JaredFarrish. I will give this a try very shortly. I greatly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Nothing happened (see my revised script above in my original question. In my IE Console all I saw was
`LOG: [object Object]
LOG: [object Object]
LOG: 0
LOG: [object Object]
LOG: 0`

Comment: It's working right. The `0` is the value of the `input` that was selected. Run it in Firefox or Chrome instead; the console output is more descriptive and useful IMO.

Comment: Thanks @JaredFarrish, but what I am trying to capture is the **id** of `es_user_2012_0076_1`, `es_user_2012_0076_2`, `es_user_2012_0076_3`, or `es_user_2012_0076_4`... and not the **value**. Reason: I want to first go to the database and load the value into the web form before focus hits the frame

Comment: Then get the `id` instead: [`console.log('id: ' + $textinputs.attr('id'));`](http://jfcoder.com/test/prettyphotoiframe.html)

Comment: Awesome @JaredFarish. I am (you're) so close to what I am trying to get. The revised script (segment 3) in my Question now returns the ID but only ID `*_1`. Each time I step through the 4 frames, id `*_1` comes up each time. I need to get id `*_1` and `*_2` and `*_3` and `*_4` respective to their frames.

Comment: As I look more closely, it is actually returning the *_1 id of the very first PP frame. I happened to click into the series of frames about 2/3's down my list and it is not returning the proper frame. It returns es_user_2012_0080_1 (each time) when I actually clicked on row es_user_0014_1. So I was expecting id's es_user_0014_1, es_user_0014_2, es_user_0014_3, es_user_0014_4 but actually got es_user_0080_1, es_user_0080_1, es_user_0080_1, es_user_0080_1

Comment: Yes, I noticed that but I hadn't resolved it before; I needed to ask you the following question. What I'm confused about (and I'm sick, so this may just be my cloudiness) is what you're attempting to do: *determine if the value in an `input` and `textarea` changes*. What's confusing about this is *when* you need to check; is it before the PP box opens, while someone is typing or interacting with the fields in question, or when the PP box closes? This will have a big impact on how to answer this question.

Comment: sorry to hear you're not feeling well. I appreciate your coming back to this. Here's what I need to do: bottom-line is I need to know the ID before any PP frame gets loaded. Here's why: the app right now has 110 rows in the DB. It can easily grow to double or triple at any given time in the future. Each row gets 4 pp frames. That part is static. So I dynamically coded the ID's of each frame in order to know where I am at any given point. Given the volume of info to be displayed, I want to populate the PP frame before it gets displayed via an Ajax call to the server & DB <more>

Comment: And since what I am presenting in each PP frame is a web form, I need to control when the user enters a value in the "es_*" <input> element and the "en_*" <textarea> element. When they do I immediately write back to the DB via Ajax. That part I tested and works fine. But given the PP frames are static and loaded upon page render, I have no way of retaining what the user enters into each form field without a call back to the server before the PP frame gets loaded. Hope this app-logic makes sense.

Comment: Another note for further clarification. As I stated in part 1 of this 3 part note, As each PP frame gets loaded I want to make a call back to the server to read the DB and grab all info related to the row and the info related to what appears in the PP Frame. This way I present what is current in the db record and I also minimize build a very huge web page that gets downloaded.

Comment: It does, but... I think you're overthinking it in the wrong direction. What you want is to trap the click of the `a` which opens, do your data search, and then return to the click and let the PP open. Try this demo of a click handler and notice the `alert()` fires before and blocks the PP display, yet you still get the right elements: http://jsfiddle.net/mSuHS/

Comment: So what I think you're going to want to do is run your AJAX within a click handler added to the `a` element before the PP is added (thus running before it), set `async: false` on the `$.ajax()` option so it blocks the PP, then set the data. Also, if I were doing it, I wouldn't load all of the actual boxes in the page load as static markup, I would create them dynamically on the `a` click, and have the AJAX callback open the PP box.

Comment: Right...I am ultimately trying to completely create each PP frame dynamically. But what about this scenario (provided you know how PP works & I assume you do). The visitor is in PP frame 2 for example, then enters their <input> element value and their <textarea> element value. Next they click the PP next button to go to PP Frame 3. But they decide to go back to PP frame 2 to see if they entered what they wanted too correctly. If I don't call back to the server and populate the frame each time it comes into focus, then won't frame 2 have the original data and not what they user just entered?

Comment: You have to think of what's going on in the browser as a distinct application; it needs to be designed as one. Looking at PP and how it handles it's content, I think what you're trying to do may not work (or be easy to make work), since what PP does is *copy* the content into it's own content, which seems asinine to me, as well as "overwriting" what has been entered. This works against the functionality you're trying to achieve (since it doesn't save state and introduces another identical element with the same `id`).

Comment: For what you're trying to do, you need to use a [jQuery UI Modal Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form), which is designed to handle what you're trying accomplish (PP is a photo browser tool). You may have to build in some of the details you want (like the left/right buttons), but you'll be better off in the end.

Comment: Ok. the app is too mature at this point. So I will end up adding notes or something that tells the user to refresh the browser in order to see what they entered. Oh, well. Thought I was trying to create a slick end-user app. But I know that "the best laid plans...." Take care and thanks for your help.

Comment: You could probably make it work somehow, but what you would need to investigate how it stores it's displayed content, how to get to it there, change that content, AND change the content in the form (what is displayed is not actually in the form). PP is not a great tool for things other than photo viewing/browsing, so beware when you choose a plugin or approach. You live and learn on things sometimes.

Comment: Thanks @JaredFarrish. Those are all the things that I intuitively know need to be done. I am a PHP coder and I only dabble in jQuery -- looking at examples of what works and try to tweak from there. I'll keep at it. I gotta believe somewhere there is a jQuery command that can see all elements within any given frame -- that is what <a> anchor tag ID is the visitor viewing and which of the 4 frames is the visitor viewing. Once I can intercept those 2 data-items I have the ajax and backend stuff to complete my app. Best to you....

Comment: Ok, take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mSuHS/6/ Click the first line (I've shown the actual markup underneath on purpose), and watch how the values update before it displays. Close the PP then click the same one. Notice how it never updates the PP box? I have a suspicion of why, but let me look at it a little further.

Comment: @Dr.DOT - Take a look at this and let me know if this is interesting or not: http://jsfiddle.net/rBNCC/ (Note, don't worry too much about what's happening, just if the functionality seems to work how you want. I'll explain and answer any questions or comments you have.)

Comment: Hey @JaredFarrish...I ran it and entered a "7" in the input box and "test in the textarea. Then I clicked on the next button to go to frame 2. Then I click on the previous button to go back to frame 1 and the values I entered were there!! That's the behavior I am looking for. Can we capture the ID in each frame and make an ajax call to the server before each frame loads?

Comment: @Dr.DOT - I already have a dummy `$.ajax()` call in there that's standing in for the real call you're going to make. Check it out and see if you can make it work; I'm going to go to bed here in a minute. I probably need to explain what I've done, so if you can leave me a time CST tomorrow (Sunday) you'll be available, I can start a chat with you here, or try farrish/j/AT/g/mail, just send me an email.

Comment: @Dr.DOT - Also note that I'm using [Live Query](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) to add the click handlers on PPs version of the elements, so you'll at least need that library to get this to work. I don't believe there is a way around this, either, since there is no callback to use from PP after the PP is appended but before the PP is opened.